# "Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'float *' with an Ivalue of type 'float'" compiler error

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, for-loop

I am making a game in xcode with c++, opengl and GLUT. I have a model which has its own .h and .cpp file and I have drawn it but I now want to translate it. I can't use gltranslate because I want to move only the gun, not my camera. The model file goes as follows:

*//M4.h*

```
extern unsigned int M4NumVerts;
extern float M4Verts [151248];
extern float M4Normals [140064];
extern float M4TexCoords [153680];
```

*//M4.cpp*

```
unsigned int M4NumVerts = 37812;

float M4Verts [151248] = {
// f 1/1/1 1582/2/1 4733/3/1
-0.00205801177070031, 0.0252329378141267, -0.266482197565778,
-0.00205347560809555, 0.015738643990207, -0.265580239652506,
-0.00908273427886488, 0.018200092410135, -0.264843587943923,...};

float M4Normals [140064] = {
// f 1/1/1 1582/2/1 4733/3/1
-0.1361849642872, -0.0937589754128839, -0.986236741371776,
-0.1361849642872, -0.0937589754128839, -0.986236741371776,
-0.1361849642872, -0.0937589754128839, -0.986236741371776,...};

float M4TexCoords [153680] = {
// f 1/1/1 1582/2/1 4733/3/1
0.110088, 0.229552,
0.108891, 0.243519,
0.119508, 0.240861,..};
```

I have a function in my math class that translates the points like this:

```
void Math::translatePoint(float P[3], float x, float y, float z){
P[0] += x;
P[1] += y;
P[2] += z;
}
```

The function works for one point if I do the following:

```
  Math::translatePoint(M4Verts[x], 0, 0, -0.5);
```

I want it to work for all the points so I made this for loop:

```
for (int x = 0; x < M4NumVerts; x++) {
    Math::translatePoint(M4Verts[x], 0, 0, -0.5);
}
```

I do this but it wont work and I am met with the error:

**Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'float *' with an Ivalue of type 'float'**

I have searched around and tried to find alternatives like defining x as a float instead but nothing I try works. Can anybody help.

Comment: I don't see what you are trying to do by writing `Math::translatePoint(M4Verts[x], 0, 0, -0.5);`. The first argument of that function is supposed to take a pointer to the first element of an array of 3 `float`s. You could write `Math::translatePoint(&M4Verts[x], 0, 0, -0.5);` (i. e. take the address of the element), but then again, with `x++`, you only achieve erroneous behavior. What's your goal? The declaration and usage of your variables and function really doesn't make sense.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, this has nothing to do with Xcode.

Comment: Try removing the subscript when passing the array:  `Math::translatePoint(M4Verts, 0, 0, -0.5)`.

Answer (score 1):

translatePoints expects an array of float of length 3. But you are passing a single float. Hence the compiler error. I'm afraid that I cannot discern what you are trying to do and so suggest the code that would be correct.

Comment: How can I make an array of float of length 3 in a for loop?

Comment: What do you actually want to do?

Comment: translate the points with a for loop by having a float of length 3 translate every point from the array of vertexes.

Comment: You've got an array of scalars. But you seem to want to operate on 3 vectors. How do you want to reconcile that? Are the first 3 scalars one vector. And the. Next 3 the next vector? Or what? Describe your data.